# What's the attribute in <mat-option> that checks/unchecks checkboxes?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

I've been trying to dynamically check/uncheck the checkbox in mat-option. What's the attribute that would handle this. I've done the same thing in mat-checkbox using [(ngModel)]. Here's my code:

app.component.html

```
<mat-option [value]="item.name">{{item.name}}</mat-option>
```

app.component.ts

```
item = {name:'Option1', checked:true};
```

Comment: mat-select works in such a way that you cannot decide the option selected in mat-option selector.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: If you scroll down to [these](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples) examples you will find out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

it should work but you have a typo, try below code with **checked**,

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked">{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>


item = {name:'Option1', checked:true};
```

for mat-select with ngModel,

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

in ts file,

```
  selected = 'option2';
```

You have ngModel on mat-select rather than on mat-option

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong example. It works in <mat-checkbox. I'm trying to figure out what attribute would work in <mat-option>. [(ngModel)] doesn't work in <mat-option>. I've updated the code example.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, how does checkboxes attached with mat-select? can you show your full code on what you are trying to do? 
do you to show selected results ? @JoshuaFernandes